# "Something's wrong, perhaps a missing \item" error when using itemize

Tags: list, latex

I'm trying to make list using itemize, and I honestly can't see whats wrong with this. I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{}
\title{Essay research}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\section{Alternative fuel sources}
Thorium based nuclear power stations offer advantages over classic uranium based ones:
\begin{itemize}:
\item Thorium-232 is much more abundant than Uranium-235
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error thrown back:

```
./Essay notes.tex:9: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [ \item T]
 ./Essay notes.tex:9: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [ \item T]
 ./Essay notes.tex:9: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [ \item T]
 ./Essay notes.tex:10: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [\end{itemize}]
```

Comment: I am a fool just found the extra : I decided to add in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got a ":" after `\begin{itemize}`.

Anything enclosed between `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` must be after `\item`.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was trying to apply `[noitemsep]` to a list, but I haven't imported the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Solved my mistery!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was in the context of a BibTex BBL file, which, upon inspection was empty.

Apparently, Overleaf reported the .bib file's name as `Mendeley.bib` and I included `\bibliography{Mendeley}`, but the file was silently not found.

**Solution:** I renamed the .bib file to all lower case and updated the `\bibliography` entry to match and everything worked as expected.

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I removed all contents in the file 'root.bib' and saved and compiled the LaTex.
It worked for me.